# pinescript strategy question : how to post a limit order on the certain level on the next opening?

Tags: pine-script, trading

i had coded an indicator which gives me entry signals after the closing of the candle but i want to use another indicator (which is calculated at the opening of the candle) as a level for setting a limit order but the strategy sets a limit order on the previous value and not on the actual one ,how can i do to receive the signal to enter a position after closing and set a limit order to entry on the next opening ?
[image]

```
   //@version=4

strategy(title="On Balance Swings[AA]", overlay=false)

f_security(_symbol, _res, _src, _repaint) => 
   security(_symbol, _res, _src[_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

res = input(title="Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="")
rep = input(title="Allow Repainting?", type=input.bool, defval=false)
bar = input(title="Allow Bar Color Change?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
lbLength = input(title="LookBackLength", type=input.integer, defval=2, minval=1)
sigLength = input(title="SignalLength", type=input.integer, defval=30, minval=1)



hg= (high-open)
lg= (open-low)
mchange = change(close)
obs=0.0
if mchange>0
   obs:=nz(obs[1])+hg
else
   obs:=nz(obs[1])-lg
ovrSma = sma(obs, sigLength)

sig = obs > ovrSma ? 1 : obs < ovrSma ? -1 : 0
alertcondition(crossover(sig, 0), "Buy Signal", "Bullish Change Detected")
alertcondition(crossunder(sig, 0), "Sell Signal", "Bearish Change Detected")
ovrColor = sig > 0 ? color.green : sig < 0 ? color.red : color.black
barcolor(bar ? ovrColor : na)
plot(obs, title="OBS", linewidth=2, color=ovrColor)
plot(ovrSma, title="SIG", linewidth=1, color=color.orange)

//gsv

lenght = input(4, minval=1 ,title="lenght")
multi = input (1.8,minval=0.1,title="multiplier")
bg=sma(hg,lenght)
sg=sma(lg,lenght)
bgsv =((bg[1]*multi)+open),offset=1
sgsv=open-(sg[1]*multi)


LC=crossover(obs,ovrSma)
SC=crossunder(obs,ovrSma)

if (crossover(obs,ovrSma))
   strategy.exit("S")
   strategy.entry("L", strategy.long, stop=bgsv, oca_name="obs", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="obsL")
else
   strategy.cancel(id="L")
if (crossunder(obs,ovrSma))
   strategy.exit("L")
   strategy.entry("S", strategy.short, stop=sgsv, oca_name="obs", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="obsS")
else
   strategy.cancel(id="S")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hoping to place an order for a level that is unknown at the time you place the order, so can't be done. You'll need to wait until your script knows the level, then place either a market order at the close, or a limit order which may not be executed.